# AR glasses available for vuforia and unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am currently building an ar system using unity and vuforia.

I would like to eventually make it work with ARglass.
I am currently looking for a candidate for ARglass.

From the official vuforia website, the following are supported by the vuforia engine.

- MICROSOFT HOLOLOLENS 2
- REALWEAR NAVIGATOR 500
- REALWEAR HMT-1Z1
- MAGIC LEAP 1,2
- TABLET/MOBILE

REALWEAR may not be compatible with modeltarget.

**Are there any other ARglass products that have been confirmed to work other than those listed here?**

**Also, if ARglass is loaded with android os, does it correspond to TABLET/MOBILE and can it be used?**

We would like to know.